# How to remove click event on "this" object in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

My `DOM` structure is as follows,

```
<a id='c_1' class='like'>Like</a>
<a id='c_2' class='like'>Like</a>
<a id='c_3' class='like'>Like</a>
......
```

Binding `click` event as follows,

```
$(document).on("click",".like",function(){
      var selector = $(this);
      saveLikes(selector);       
});
```

`saveLikes(selector)` have `Ajax` call,on `success` of `Ajax` call I want to remove/unbind `click` event on currently clicked element for that I've written following code in `success` callback.

```
$(document).off("click",selector);
```

It's not working and I'm able to remove `click` event by  `$(document).off("click",".like");` but I don't want this because further clicks on other elements will not fire the event.

***Is their any solution to remove event on current element only that too without changing class name ?***

Answer (score 2):

In this case you

```
$(document).on("click",".like",function(){
    var selector = $(this);
    if(selector.data('liked')){
        return;
    }

    saveLikes(selector);     
    selector.data('liked', true)
});
```

Or

```
$(document).on("click",".like:not(.liked)",function(){
    var selector = $(this).addClass('liked');
    saveLikes(selector);     
});
```

Comment: +1... `selector.data('liked', true)` should be moved to the success callback .. I believe

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Is their any solution without changing class name ?

Comment: @Mahesh.D you have the first one, in the second one the class name is not changed, we are adding a new class

Answer (score 1):

This one...

```
$('#foo').unbind('click', function() {
    alert('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.');
});
```

[REFERENCE: .unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would help

```
$( "#foo" ).one( "click", function(){
    alert( "This will be displayed only once.");
});
```

The `Click` event is executed just once for that particular ID and unbinds it automatically.

**REFERENCE**: [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Answer (score 0):

Updated code

```
$(".like").click(function() {
    var selector = $(this);
    saveLikes(selector);
    selector.off('click');       // <- Put this in Ajax success
});
```

Comment: What I've asked and what you have given answer ? will not match at all,thanks.

Comment: @Baadshah: Sorry if you felt in that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `add click event once` then you can use [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one) for this,

like,

```
$('.like').one("click",function(){
      var selector = $(this);
      saveLikes(selector);       
});
```